# how select a dynamic id generated in php with jquery

Tags: jquery, select

this code generated in php 
id="sus- ... <--- is static
and id="sus-d->id ?>" is my problem to select that

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="sus-<?= $D->d->id ?>" ><i class="icon-trash "></i></button>
```

out put :

id="sus-2131"

so i want select all id's start with

> sus-

with below function :

```
jQuery('#sus-').btsConfirmButton({msg:"I'm sure!"}, function(e) {
        d_manage('delete','<?= $D->d->id?>');$(this).slideUp();
    });
```

that it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the starts with selector [**^=**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like

```
jQuery('[id^="sus-"]').btsConfirmButton({msg:"I'm sure!"}, function(e) {
        d_manage('delete','<?= $D->d->id?>');$(this).slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: so how can i get a number for each in jqeury? like sus-24  **number** in some jquery variable in function

Comment: @imanaletaha, do you mean you want the number *24* in a variable?

Comment: yes i want use that  in `d_manage('delete',**NUMBER**);$(this).slideUp();`

Comment: try `var number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];`

Answer (score 0):

If you made each item use the css class "sus" instead you might be able to select them all with something list $('.suss').each()...

You would then be able to iterate over each "sus" item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want suspend something .. so i should use ID for suspend unique item

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector:

```
$('[id^=sus]').btsConfirmButton({msg:"I'm sure!"}, function(e) {
   d_manage('delete','<?= $D->d->id?>');$(this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: so how can i get a number for each in jqeury? like sus-24  **number** in some jquery variable in function